# Erro ao adicionar controlador mvc usando o entity framework

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação MVC usando Entity Framework Core, e o Asp.Net Core MVC 5, usando o MySql através do Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql,  a classe de domínio é definida como:

```
public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}
```

Meu DbContext é definido como:

```
 public class EscolaDbContexto: DbContext
{
    

    public EscolaDbContexto(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
    {
        

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        List<Aluno> seed = new List<Aluno>()
        {
            new Aluno(){Nome = "Sebastião", DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime("31/07/1984")},
            new Aluno(){Nome = "José", DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime("01/03/1985") },
            new Aluno(){Nome = "Pedro", DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime("01/07/1987") }


        };
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>().HasData(seed);
    }
    public DbSet<Aluno> Albuns { get; set; }
    
}
```

E meu appsetings.json é definido como:

Além de configurar no Startup.cs da seguinte forma

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<Models.Contexto
            .EscolaDbContexto>(options => options
            .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EscolaDbContext")));
    }
```

No entanto, quando tento criar um controller usando o gerador de código "Controlador MVC com exibições, usando o Entity Framework, selecionando a classe Aluno, como domínio e EscolaDbContext como contexto de dados, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
{
"Logging":{
    "LogLevel":{
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft":"Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
},
"ConnectionStrings":{
    "EscolaDbContext":"server=127.0.0.1; port=3306;database=escolaDb;uid=root;password=1234"
},
"AllowedHosts":"*"
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

[Edit]No scaffolding, está escrito "Controlador MVC com exibições, usando o Entity Framework", e eu estou usando o Entity Framework Core. Não seria este gerador de código incompatível com essa versão?

Comment: sempre tem a possibilidade de criar a controller vazia e por o código manualmente, ai pode testar a sua implementação e ver se não tem nenhum erro de código ou configuração, o *scaffolding* às vezes dá erro e não mostra o que é

Comment: Não deve está influenciando, mas tem erro de grafia aqui "public DbSet<Aluno> Albuns { get; set; }
". Já tentou rodar por linha de comando o Scaffolding do EF?